# applying a created function in a list with data frames

Tags: r, list, dataframe, apply

I would like to calculate the variation coefficient in a list composed of several data frames. However, when I apply my function that calculates the variation coeficient in my list of data frames I am getting this error:

```
coef_var = lapply(dists_log, cvs) 
Error in is.data.frame(x) : 
  'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'
```

Here what I did:

```
List = list  (A = data.frame(A = rnorm(30), B = rnorm(30), C =rnorm (30), D = rnorm(30)),
       B = data.frame(A = rnorm(30), B = rnorm(30), C =rnorm (30), D = rnorm(30)),
       C = data.frame(A = rnorm(30), B = rnorm(30), C =rnorm (30), D = rnorm(30)),
       D = data.frame(A = rnorm(30), B = rnorm(30), C =rnorm (30), D = rnorm(30)))

#function to calculate the variation coeficient
cvs <- function (dist){
  cv  <-  sd(dist, na.rm=T) / mean(dist, na.rm=T) * 100
  return(cv)
}

The I run:
coef_var = lapply(dists_log, cvs)

and got the error message above
```

Can someone help me with this error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need a nested `list` as `sd` and `mean` requires the input to be `vector` and not a data.frame.  So, we loop over the columns of the `data.frame` with `lapply`, apply the 'cvs' function, assign back to the object and return the data.frame object

```
lapply(dists_log, function(x) {x[] <- lapply(x, cvs); x})
```

If we are expecting only a single element as output

```
lapply(dists_log, function(x) unlist(lapply(x, cvs)))
```

Comment: My guess is something like `lapply(dists_log, function(x) sapply(x, cvs))` may be what OP wants, since the CV is just a single value for each column.

Comment: Thanks, @akrun and @Adam. Both solutions (`lapply(dists_log, function(x) unlist(lapply(x, cvs)))` and `lapply(dists_log, function(x) sapply(x, cvs))` worked perfectly.